# Include XML CDATA in an element

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

**UPDATE: Added more detail per request**

I am trying to create an xml configuration file for my application. The file contains a list of criteria to search and replace in an html document. The problem is, I need to search for character strings like `&nbsp`. I do not want my code to read the decoded item, but the text itself.

Admitting to being very new to XML, I did make some attempts at meeting the requirements. I read a load of links here on Stackoverflow regarding `CDATA` and `ATTRIBUTES` and so on, but the examples here (and elsewhere) seem to focus on creating one single line in an xml file, not multiple.

Here is one of many attempts I have made to no avail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE item [
  <!ELEMENT item (id, replacewith)>
  <!ELEMENT id (#CDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT replacewith (#CDATA)>
  ]>
]>
<item id=" " replacewith="&nbsp;">Non breaking space</item>
<item id="&#8209;" replacewith="-">Non breaking hyphen</item>
```

This document gives me a number of errors, including:

- In the DOCTYPE, I get errors like `<!ELEMENT id (#CDATA)>`. In the CDATA area, Visual Studio informs me it is expecting a ',' or '|'.
- `]>` gives me an error of `invalid token at the root of the document`.
- And of course, after the second `<item` entry, I get an error stating `XML document cannot contain multiple root level elements`.

How can I write an xml file that includes multiple items **and** allows me to store and retrieve the text within the element, rather than the interpreted characters?

If it helps any, I am using .Net, C#, and Visual Studio.

**EDIT:**
The purpose of this xml file is to provide my code with a list of things to search and replace in an html file. The xml file simply contains a list of `what to search for` and `what to replace with`.

Here is the file I have in place right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Items>
  <item id="&#8209;" replacewith="-">Non breaking hyphen</item>
  <item id=" " replacewith="&nbsp;">Non breaking hyphen</item>
</Items>
```

Using the first  as an example, I want to read the text `&#8209` but instead when I read this, I get `-` because that is what the code represents.

Any help or pointers you can give would be helpful.

Comment: Unclear what you trying to achieve. Sample of *valid* XML that you want to see would help. If you are trying to read/write XML with string manipulations/regex - please stop doing so (or at least don't ask about it on SO).

Comment: I have updated the description with more detail and the xml file I am using. Basically, I am trying to compile a list of strings that I want to search and replace in an html file. These strings are configurable by a user, so I figured I would store them in an xml config file. I basically want to read the text contained within the attribute as a raw string rather than a decoded string.

Comment: If you want the text, encode it. For example, NBSP would be `&amp;nbsp;`

Comment: @Bill - Does this encoding work for you? I also added a link in my answer to an entities list in case it's of value to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: XML acts like HTML due to the reserved characters. An ampersand prefixes keywords or character codes to translate into a literal string when read in with any type of parser (browser, XML reader, etc).

The easiest way to escape the values to make sure they are read back in as the literal that you want is to put them in as if you were encoding it for web. For example, to create your XML document, I did this:

```
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     XmlElement xmlItem;
     XmlAttribute xmlAttr;
     XmlText xmlText;

     // Declaration
     XmlDeclaration xmlDec = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
     XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
     xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDec, xmlRoot);

     // Items
     XmlElement xmlItems = xmlDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Items", string.Empty);
     xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlItems);

     // Item #1
     xmlItem = xmlDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "item", string.Empty);
     xmlAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(string.Empty, "id", string.Empty);
     xmlAttr.Value = "&#8209;";
     xmlItem.Attributes.Append(xmlAttr);
     xmlAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(string.Empty, "replacewith", string.Empty);
     xmlAttr.Value = "-";
     xmlItem.Attributes.Append(xmlAttr);
     xmlText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Non breaking hyphen");
     xmlItem.AppendChild(xmlText);

     xmlItems.AppendChild(xmlItem);

     // Item #2
     xmlItem = xmlDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "item", string.Empty);
     xmlAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(string.Empty, "id", string.Empty);
     xmlAttr.Value = " ";
     xmlItem.Attributes.Append(xmlAttr);
     xmlAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(string.Empty, "replacewith", string.Empty);
     xmlAttr.Value = "&nbsp;";
     xmlItem.Attributes.Append(xmlAttr);
     xmlText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("Non breaking hyphen");
     xmlItem.AppendChild(xmlText);

     xmlItems.AppendChild(xmlItem);

     // For formatting
     StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
     {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "  ",
        NewLineChars = "\r\n",
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
     };
     using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlBuilder, xmlSettings))
     {
        xmlDoc.Save(writer);
     }

     xmlOutput.Text = xmlBuilder.ToString();
```

Notice that I put in your `id` values with what you are expecting. Now, look at how it gets encoded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Items>
  <item id="&amp;#8209;" replacewith="-">Non breaking hyphen</item>
  <item id=" " replacewith="&amp;nbsp;">Non breaking hyphen</item>
</Items>
```

The only difference between yours and this one is that the ampersand was encoded as `&amp;` and the rest remained as a string literal. This is normal behavior for XML. When you read it back in, it will come back as the literal `&#8209;` and `&nbsp;`.

Comment: This approach also happens for other reserved characters, such as `<` changing to `&lt;` and `>` changing to `&gt;` (and vice versa). For more entity fun, check out this: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for offering this up. I will test today. I think the main difference here is you have come up with a way to just create a simple XML document and store the information whereas I was trying to force XML to treat the text as literal strings. At this point, I am open to any solution that works :-)

Comment: I was just showing that when you generate an XML document, it automatically encodes it correctly. If you were to do it by hand, you'd need to manually encode it, such as `&amp;#8209;`. Basically, just replace your first instance of an ampersand in each attribute with `&amp;`

Comment: If you use any type of XML reader to retrieve the attribute value of `&amp;#8209;`, it will come back in as `&#8209;`

Comment: Thank you. My code is in beta so I am just letting the users modify the XML through the UI. I like your approach but clearly need to prioritize the UI implementation first to avoid them typing something wrong. It is already a little confusing since my users are not XML experts.

Comment: If you're using a UI to do it, it would be really easy to refactor my code into reusable methods to allow for infinite "item" elements. Then you can let your users use a ListView in Detail mode, a DataGrid, or a similar grid-like implementation. No XML knowledge needed.

Comment: Yup. We are on the same page.